# Json Jackson deserialize object without setters

Tags: java, jackson

I have class(for example. In real project I have JAXB generated class instead User):

```
public class User {
  private List<String> users;

  public List<String> getUsers() {
    return users;
  }
}
```

When I get User user(with data) I can serialize it to String or byte[] with JacksonJson. But when I try deserialize it to `User` I get error:

```
Cannot construct instance of `javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

Because User has not setter. How can I deserialize it?

Comment: Why don't you want to use setters? It's just a POJO after all.

Comment: he use generated class

Comment: you have to provide more information. I tried deserializing with the provided class, but it works fine. Can you post the pojo with the annotations that are generated in the pojo? Also, please provide, if you have other custom configurations done for the `ObjectMapper`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by implement custom deserializer class.

Try with this:

```
String json = null;//your request json
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer(User.class,new UserDeserialzer());
User user = objectMapper.registerModule(module).readValue(json,User.class);
```

Deserializer class:

```
public class UserDeserialzer extends JsonDeserializer<User>{
    @Override
    public User deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode value = new ObjectMapper().readTree(p.getText());
        User user = new User();
        try {
            Field field = user.getClass().getDeclaredField("users");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(user,value.get("users"));
        }catch (Exception ex){
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

**For Spring-boot application** :

add this bean to deserialize globally.

```
@Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder configureObjectMapper() {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addDeserializer(User.class,new UserDeserialzer());
        objectMapper.registerModule(module);
        builder.configure(objectMapper);
        return builder;
    }
```

Comment: I said the class is auto-generated. I can not change it

Comment: implement deserializer class. then set value by refleciton

Comment: try with this. if you use spring/ spring-boot then can add configuration class for global deserialization for user.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to use Apache CXF while creating JAXB objects, you can use xjc plugin to create setter-getter methods automatically during generated objects. This way may be very pratical for you.

I ran into the same problem and in this way, I solved the problem without making a code change.

You can add the following part to your pom file:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.apache.cxf}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/sample.wsdl</wsdl>
                                <wsdlLocation>classpath:wsdl/sample.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                                <extraargs>
                                    <extraarg>-xjc-Xbg</extraarg>
                                    <extraarg>-xjc-Xcollection-setter-injector</extraarg>
                                </extraargs>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf.xjcplugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-xjc-boolean</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.3</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.andromda.thirdparty.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>collection-setter-injector</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```